# Is there a Clojure macro equivalent to def?

Tags: function, clojure, macros

I want to write a macro, `sym-def`, which has the same behavior as the special form `def` but uses `(symbol "c")`, say, as the first argument.

My first step was

```
(def (symbol "c") 4)
```

but this returned the error `First argument to def must be a Symbol`.

My second step was

```
(eval `(def ~(symbol "c") 4))
```

and this succeeded in defining `c` to be 4 in the global environment.
Why did my first step fail while the second step succeeded?

Finally, I attempted to write the desired macro

```clj
(defmacro sym-def [sym value] `(def ~sym ~value))
```

but this has a "bad" `macroexpand`

```clj
(macroexpand '(sym-def (symbol "c") 4)) => (def (symbol "c") 4)
```

so that

```clj
(sym-def (symbol "c") 4)
```

fails with the same error as my first step.

What is the correct way to write the macro?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`def` does not evaluate its first argument. Imagine the chaos if it did! You couldn't write

```
(def x 1)
```

because it would first try to evaluate `x`, and fail because `x` is not yet defined! Now, since it doesn't evaluate its arguments, clearly it makes sense that

```
(def (symbol "c") 4)
```

doesn't work, just as

```
(def 'c 4)
```

wouldn't. `def` requires its first argument to be a literal symbol. You don't have a literal symbol, so you can't use `def`.

But there is a lower-level mechanism to interact with the mappings in a namespace. In this case, you want `clojure.core/intern`:

```
(intern *ns* (symbol "c") 4)
```

`intern` is an ordinary function, so it evaluates all its arguments, meaning you can construct your var name in whatever crazy way you want. Then it adds to the given namespace a var mapping your symbol to its desired value.

Comment: ... So we could define `def` as a macro in terms of `intern` ... using `defmacro` defined in terms of ... oops ... `def`.

Comment: If def requires its first argument to be a literal symbol, why does (eval `(def ~(symbol "c") 4)) work?

Comment: @cfgauss you're evaluating the "unquoted" inner part first, so when it gets to eval it's already in the form it needs to be.

Comment: @cfgauss Try removing the `eval` there: it evaluates to `(def c 4)`. And then, of course running `eval` on the result of that is perfectly fine: `def`'s argument is a literal symbol *when `def` is actually called*.

Comment: @Thumbnail Even if bootstrapping weren't a problem, you couldn't actually do this, because `def` allows circular definitions like `(def factorial (fn [x] (if (zero? x) 1, (* x (factorial (dec x))))))`. `intern` can't allow this.

Answer (score 2):

A correct form for the macro you want to write is the following:

```clj
(defmacro sym-def [s v] `(def ~(eval s) ~v))
```

... or equivalently:

```clj
(defmacro sym-def [s v] (list `def (eval s) v))
```

You just need to evaluate the first argument inside the macro, because a macro's arguments are not evaluated when it is applied. If the only symbol-producing expressions you are going to use are calls to `symbol`, you may prefer the following macro:

```clj
(defmacro defsym [s v] (list `def (symbol s) v))
```

... and a companion to it:

```clj
(defmacro sym [s] (symbol s))
```

These macros translate a string or symbol to a symbol. Here are some examples of their use:

```clj
(defsym "the first natural number" 0)
;=> #'user/the first natural number
(sym "the first natural number")
;=> 0
(defsym pi 3.14159) ;same as: (def pi 3.14159)
;=> #'user/pi
(sym pi) ;same as: pi
;=> 3.14159
```

The variations given below might also be usefull:

```clj
(defmacro defsym* [s v] (list `def (symbol (eval s)) v))
(defmacro sym* [s] (symbol (eval s)))
```

They translate a string/symbol-producing expression to a symbol after evaluating it. Here are some examples of `defsym*`'s use:

```clj
(defsym* "abc" "xyz")
(defsym* (str \a \b \c) "xyz")
(defsym* (symbol "abc") "xyz")
(defsym* 'abc "xyz")
;all the previous are equivalent and what follows is valid for any of them
;=> #'user/abc
abc
;=> "xyz"
(defsym* abc 0)
;=> #'user/xyz
abc
;=> "xyz"
xyz
;=> 0
```